# Variables used in SendKeys do not have spaces in Python?

Tags: python, variables, sendkeys

I am using SendKeys in Python to write in another program (notepad), in which it is writing a variable. But when it prints the variable in Notepad it doesn't print the spaces in the string. Here's the code:

```
import SendKeys 

if msg['from'] == '********@live.com':
        SendKeys.SendKeys("""
        {LWIN}
        {PAUSE .25}
        notepad.exe{ENTER}
        {PAUSE 1}
        %s
        """ % (body))
```

Now, let's say that the variable 'body' is 'Test test'- Python prints the variable as 'Test test', while when SendKeys types it in Notepad it prints the variable as 'Testtest'. Is there a different way to print variables in SendKeys that includes the spaces?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/), `with_spaces` should do the trick.

```
import SendKeys 

if msg['from'] == '********@live.com':
        SendKeys.SendKeys("""
        {LWIN}
        {PAUSE .25}
        notepad.exe{ENTER}
        {PAUSE 1}
        %s
        """ % (body), with_spaces=True)
```

I hope to Ghu, though, that you're not *starting Notepad through the GUI* rather than just writing your data to a file the normal Python way...

Comment: Ahh! You know, I looked at that, and for some reason thought it wouldn't work with variables... Thank you so much! And actually, I was using this with another program but when I realised it didn't work I switched back to Notepad for simplicity's sake. Thanks again!